# Play Sound in MonoTouch for specific duration

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Using the MonoTouch libraries, what I would like to do is being able to play a sound for a specific duration and then stop playback. It must be done on a different thread than the UI. I've tinkered with a few different options, and I'm not entirely sure what the best course of action is at this point.

The classes look something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public double Duration { get; set; }
    public double PauseAfter { get; set; }
}

public class FooPlayer
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    public void PlayFoos()
    {
        foreach (Foo f in Foos)
        {
             //Play the sound
             //Stop the sound after the duration has passed
             //Wait for the duration specified in PauseAfter
             //Continue loop
        }
    }
}
```

I've been tinkering with SystemSound and AvAudioPlayer but I'm yet to get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer, and after the timer fires stop the playback.  A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564212/how-can-you-play-a-sound-of-a-specified-duration-using-avaudioplayer-on-ios), with a similar answer (use a Timer) but in Obj-C.

Comment: The Obj-C doesn't help me very because 1) How is that Play(), being synchronous, doesn't just complete prior to the timer being started or elapsing? 2) I can't tell if there's anything in this that would be blocking the UI thread