# How to set timeout for AVPlayer

Tags: ios, timeout, avplayer

I used code like below, while I failed to find out an way to set the timeout. The default timeout is around 1min, I just want to change it to be like 10s. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:wpTrack.url];

_audioPlayer = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:playerItem]];

[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564212/how-can-you-play-a-sound-of-a-specified-duration-using-avaudioplayer-on-ios

Comment: Yea, this one should work. I will try it.

Comment: So, did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, this one works ok. Thanks.

Comment: While after talked with QA team, they don't want to change the timeout anymore, because the implementation is not an real timeout stuff. So I just comment it out later.
Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing! Happy coding